# Client side MVC Modal validation with Jquery Unobtrusive in non Razor views

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

My controller returns JsonResult and i don't want to use Razor views at all, I want plain Html pages using JQuery AJAX to make request to Controller actions. I am able to do all this but i want JQuery to validate my modal (let say while Order creation [Form validation])using Jquery unobtrusive so that i can show Dataannotation attributes error messages instead of client side validation errors.

Please see the Code below

My Controller Code is as under

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveMovies(Movie movie)
    {
        AjaxResponse response = new AjaxResponse { Success = false };
        try
        {
            _movieRepository.Add(movie);
            _movieRepository.Save();
            response.Data = "Movie added";
            response.Success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.Success = false;
            response.Message = "An exception occur while fetching data" + Environment.NewLine + "Method: " + ex.TargetSite + Environment.NewLine + "Source: " + ex.Source + Environment.NewLine + "Message: " + ex.Message;
            MoviesLogger logger = new MoviesLogger();
            logger.Error(ex);
        }
        return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

MY Jquery code is as under

```
           $("#save").click(function () {

        var movie = {
            Title: $('#TitleTextBox').val(),
            ReleaseDate: $('#ReleaseDateTextBox').val(),
            Genre: $('#GenreTextBox').val(),
        };

        if (isValid(movie)) {
            SendRequest("Movies", "SaveMovies", JSON.stringify(movie), "post", function (response) { // AJAX Success
                $("#Notification").html("Movie Added");
            }, function (response) { // AJAX Fail
                alert("Fail");
                alert(response.Message);
            });
        }
        else {
            $('#errorDiv').html(""); // THIS DIV WILL LIST ALL THE error messages FROM MY POCO CLASS DataAnnotations Attributes
        }
    });
```

Function isValid Code is as under

```
  function isValid(Movie) {
    try {
        /*
                       I WANT TO VALIDATE THE POCO MODAL(Movie) AGAINST ALL DataAnnotations Attributes set in there
                       MY Movie POCO is as under

                       public class Movie
                       {
                           [Key]
                           public int ID { get; set; }
                           [StringLength(20)]
                           [Required(ErrorMessage="Title is required")]
                           public string Title { get; set; }
                           public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
                           public string Genre { get; set; }
                       }
                       */
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Function SendRequest Code is as under

```
  function SendRequest(controller, action, data, type, onSuccess, onError) {
        if (type.toLowerCase() == 'post')
            data = JSON.stringify(data);
        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl + '/' + controller + '/' + action,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: type,
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: onSuccess,
            error: onError
        });
```

Comment: can you specify and show us some code about what have you done

Comment: i have added the code please look